# Check the command line arguments for a negative number

Tags: c, arguments

I am trying to figure out how to detect the negative numbers in argc (in c).

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]); //print what typed in the command line (arguments)
        //do an if statement here? if less than zero, any help would be great.
    } 
}
```

I am thinking where I am struggling with the if statement (hopefully I am on track). Any suggestion? Thanks.

The output I am expecting:

```
$ ./a.out 5 4 6 3 5 -5
5
4
6
3
5
-5
Sorry, you have negative value.
```

Then it will quit the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Simplify the problem. You have `char *str = "-5";`. How do you detect that it's negative?

Comment: You mean a negative number as one of the elements of `argv`, right?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Oh I see, that makes sense now I was bit confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this condition before `printf` statement in the loop

```
if(argv[i][0] == '-')
{  
    printf("Sorry, you have negative value. \n");
    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to figure it out using John K suggestion. Thanks!